# How to undisable add-on from scene?

Tags: add-on

I installed a jiggle bone for blender 2.79. However when I added it on it says that it is disabled for this scene. How do I fix that?[image]

Comment: Have you seen the scene properties ?

Comment: @Gorgious i don't know where that is tho? i tried searching but i'm not really sure

Comment: You can find it there https://blenderartists.org/uploads/default/original/4X/1/0/b/10b1815b48e138176dbde51c9bdc02f72107a2bd.png

Comment: @Gorgious i'm on blender 2.79 do you know how it looks like for that version pls?

Comment: Or, right. The icons are horizontal, not vertical in your version. Should look like that : https://i.stack.imgur.com/zQTXE.png you may have to click on one of the arrows to expand the foldout